# Can I use Blender to CREATE an iOS app?

Tags: scripting, 3d-view

I'm just a beginner in both Blender and Xcode, but I wanted to know if I make something in Blender, could I eventually TRANSFER it over to Swift to make an iOS app or is this not possible?

My ultimate goal is creating an iOS app but I know I'll need 3D components so I'm not sure if these two are compatible or if I should just stick to learning one over the other.

Comment: Personally, I think Unity and Unreal Engine are much more suited to be used to create iOS apps and other types of system applications.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that no, there is no way to create an application in Blender that can be exported.

What you can do is create scenes in Blender than can be exported in a file format that Apple's software understands like [Universal Scene Description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Scene_Description) and manipulate that data in a Swift program; *or* as [BlendMaster15](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/146160/blendermaster15) suggested in a comment on the question, you can also export the assets to a cross development system such as [Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-GettingStarted.html) or [Unreal Engine](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/SharingAndReleasing/Mobile/iOS/QuickStart/)